# machine learning models for identifying the functional transformations between two numerical sequences

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

In the practice, there is a problem where the input can be a continuous line, like waveform, the output is also a continuous line, i.e., another waveform. In the sampling space, I can get `100` samples from waveform in the original continuous space. In other words, the problem can be transformed into finding the mapping function between a numerical sequence and another numerical sequence.

For instance, the input sequence is `[-4.1288461e-16  -2.2452528e-15  -1.1717652e-14  -5.8685417e-14  -2.8203791e-13  -1.3006001e-12]`, the output sequence is `[1.2080356e-01   0.0000000e+00   0.0000000e+00   0.0000000e+00   0.0000000e+00   0.0000000e+00 ]`

In practice, we can have thousands of this kind of input-output pairs for training purposes. In the machine learning field, are there any specific models aiming to solve this kind of problem. My feeling is that neural network maybe a fit, but what kind of architecture is a better option. Here,  the output is not a categorical variables usually for classification problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general term for this kind of problem, in which you want to predict one variable using another, and you have input-output pairs with which to train a model, is "supervised learning". Supervised learning is the most common application of statistics and machine learning. Machine-learning people like to call supervised learning of a continuous variable "regression", although to statisticians, this term refers to a certain family of models. In any case, there's a wide array of tools available for such problems, from linear regression to neural networks.